# SPDZ Implementation

Tags: multiparty-computation

I am looking for a publicly available implementation of the SPDZ protocol. So far I have found the following:

[An implementation by Vitor Enes:](https://github.com/vitorenesduarte/spdz/blob/master/report.pdf) Depends on trusted dealer for offline phase.

[The Fresco project:](http://fresco.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol_suites.html#the-spdz-protocol-suite) API is not yet stable and also depends on trusted dealer for offline phase.

Is anyone aware of any implementations that also implement the offline phase?

Comment: We'll be releasing software for the SPDZ online phase and the offline phase using MASCOT at some point in the next few weeks. I'll post an answer when it's online.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/bristolcrypto/SPDZ-2) is the release.

Comment: @mikeazo Thanks for the release. Question: [The requirements](https://github.com/bristolcrypto/SPDZ-2/blob/master/README.md) says I need CPU chip with AES-NI and PCLMUL operations. Is there any software way around this?

Comment: @danxinnoble Sorry, I have no idea on that.